# Integrating a geometric series.

Tags: calculus

Please help me with the following problem.

1. Write down a closed formula for the finite sum $1-t+t^2-t^3+\cdots+(-t)^{n-1}$, integrate and deduce that when $x\geq 0$, $$x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}=\operatorname{log}(1+x)+(-1)^{n+1}\int_{0}^x\frac{t^n}{1+t}dt.$$
2. If $0\leq f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $a\leq x \leq b$ explain why $\int_a^bf(x)dx\leq \int_a^bg(x)dx$ and hence show that $$0\leq \int_0^x\frac{t^n}{1+t}dt\leq \int_0^xt^ndt\leq \frac{1}{n+1}$$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: Posting screenshots is one thing, but posting barely readable photos takes it to the next level! Please type your question as text and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: If you want people to help you, you should make it easy for them to do so.

Comment: @Lucy: I agree with Ayman, that this is very difficult to read! Can you please describe what have you tried and where you are confused?

Comment: @Lucy We can see that you are new here so you probably don't know how to write latex yet (the nice math symbols) so that's ok. I've edited your post so that it is more to the community standards. Just some general things: Please make the title more descriptive, not just "I need help". Please give the question as a request (as I've written it in the edit) and also try to avoid making us click a link just to see your question, it makes it harder to help you.

Comment: @Lucy Why have you undone the edits?

Comment: @Ragib Zaman very sorry.....i did not see your edits

Comment: very sorry....feel like a big idiot, anyways thanks for the editing...its the same thing

Comment: Seriously i have no idea, its a new topic to me

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

-- If $\,a,\,ar,\,ar^2,\,\ldots,\,ar^n,\ldots\,$ is a geometric series , then

$$S_n:=a+ar^2+ar^3+\ldots+ar^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}ar^k=\,a\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}=a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}\;,\;\;r\neq 1$$

-- Letting $\,t\,$ be a real variable, we have

$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\int\frac{t^n-1}{t-1}dt=-\log(t-1)+\int\frac{t^n}{t-1}dt$$

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the sum is a geometric series with sum $\frac {1 + (-t)^n}{1+t}$.  Can you see how it integrates as shown (despite the change of variables from $t$ to $x$), then recognize the Taylor series with error term?